# Функции для работы с изображениями

Tags: изображения, php, jpeg

**Доброго времени суток!**

Подскажите мне пожалуйста, как вывести отформатированное изображение в БРАУЗЕР, посредством PHP функции для работы с изображением `imagejpeg()` ? В JPG-файл все прекрасно выводится и впоследствии корректно отображается, но вот вывод в файл почему-то не работает. **Собственно, сначала вывод в файл:**

```
imagejpeg($img,'file.jpg',100);
```

**И в браузер:**

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($img);
```

Итог: в браузер либо не выводится ничего, если хедеры не отправлены, либо изображение в текстовом виде( что в общем тоже некорректно! ). Помогите мне пожалуйста!

**Спасибо!**

Comment: У вас есть права на запись туда куда вы пишите?

Comment: сделайте проверку на is_writable('file.jpg')

Comment: Я никуда не пишу. Я вывожу информацию из потока, как графику в браузер.

Answer (score 2):

Кажется я знаю в чем проблема, попробуй так:

```
imagejpeg($img,'file.jpg',100);
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($img,null,100);
```

Смотри первый пост в [мануале](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.imagejpeg.php)

Еще это может быть от того что ты пытаешься вывести progressive jpg не используя функцию imageinterlace(). Смотри замечание в том же мануале.

Comment: К сожалению, нет...

Comment: Ну тогда можно попробовать вывести в файл, получить имя файла и просто окружить его соответствующим HTML тэгом. Как-нибудь так:

 echo '<img style="margin:'.$margin.'px;" src="'$imgfilename'" height="'.$ht.'">';

Comment: @igumnov, памяти ограничено - картинок слишком много.

Comment: @Asen. Насколько я понял они там динамически генерируются, тогда что мешает каждый раз генерировать ее, потом выводить и потом удалять с сервера, она же окажется в конечном счете в кэше браузера и все, а не сервере ее не будет, если клиент обновляет страницу сгенерируется еще раз ничего страшного нет в этом.

Comment: @igumnov, ну а как же с нагрузкой на сервер? Если, допустим будет 100 пользователей и у каждого на странице по 300 изображений, к примеру, то что? Сервер не полетит даже от такой нагрузки?

Comment: @Asen А их не обязательно удалять сразу после того как она загружена первым пользователем, можно постепенно удалять в зависимости от количества свободного места на хостинге и количества обращений к той или иной картинке. То есть то к чему чаще обращаются сохранять, а непопулярное генерировать на лету. А так компромисс между объемами занятой памяти и производительностью очень часто встречается. Хочешь быстродействия плати памятью.